# installing Tango Core on Project Tango development kit

Tags: android, google-project-tango

I have an older development kit, and I've been trying to update to newer bits.  I used to have the "Project Tango Core" app installed, but removed it in hopes of installing "Tango Core".  However, when I attempt to install Tango Core, it won't install the app, failing with a "Duplicate Provider Authority".  Same error if I try to install the apk using adb: INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER

How can I get rid of the old tango so I can get the new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would have been better to let the play store handle the update from project tango to tango. this is , i think, a play store error message. what i would try,  is to try to find a project tango core .apk at one of the .apk sites ,  https://apkpure.com/legacy-tango-core/com.projecttango.tango . or another site you may use  see if you can install that then let the store update to the newer core.